# cap deploy error while deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

i'm getting error while deploying, i have no idea of what are the codes to be  placed here,

Error:

```
shared/system /home/ubuntu/apps/nabtat/shared/log /home/ubuntu/apps/nabtat/shared/pids"
servers: ["ec2-54-200-226-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"]
[ec2-54-200-226-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] executing command
** [out :: ec2-54-200-226-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] default: line 20: server:  command not found
** [out :: ec2-54-200-226-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] default: line 21: listen: command not found
** [out :: ec2-54-200-226-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] default: line 22: listen: command not found
** [out :: ec2-54-200-226-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] default: line 24: root: command not found
** [out :: ec2-54-200-226-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] default: line 25: index: command not found
** [out :: ec2-54-200-226-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] default: line 28: server_name: command not found
** [out :: ec2-54-200-226-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] default: line 30: location: command not found
** [out :: ec2-54-200-226-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] default: line 33: try_files: command not found
** [out :: ec2-54-200-226-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] default: line 36: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
** [out :: ec2-54-200-226-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] default: line 36: `  }'
command finished in 1371ms
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/apps/nabtat /home/ubuntu/apps/nabtat/releases /home/ubuntu/apps/nabtat/shared /home/ubuntu/apps/nabtat/shared/system /home/ubuntu/apps/nabtat/shared/log /home/ubuntu/apps/nabtat/shared/pids'" on ec2-54-200-226-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Those words showing error are in my nginx.conf file.

Comment: You've failed to paste enough logs.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing points to specific problem but try this dumb thing:

```
run "mkdir -p Whatever/paths/you/want/created", :shell => :sh
```